# How to preserve start and end space when using libtidy?

Tags: html, tidy

Input.html

```
<div><span style=font-size:11px;>1</span><span style=font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;> 2</span></div>
```

Command:

tidy Input.html

Output:

```
<div><span style="font-size:11px;">1</span> <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;">2</span></div>
```

Issue:
 The space before 2 is not there in the output.

How can I preserve the space? Space get lost if its there at the start or at the end of line.
Is using `&nbsp;` is the only way?

Comment: I also have this problem. Have you figured out a solution yet ?

Comment: Not yet :(. But after debugging the libtidy, I assumed that it does for purpose and if some one is really picky about this, he may change the code when libtidy is doing the parsing.